# How do i remove some character at the last iteration of the for loop using php?

Tags: php

```
$x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';

 for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
 {
     $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
     $x.=$y.",";

 }

    $sql= $x.')";';
    echo $sql."<br /><br />";
```

it results the following result

```
      CREATE TABLE MyGuests 
       (author VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        genre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        price VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        publish_date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       );
```

But i want to remove that "," which is after NOT NULL, at the last iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**optimal solution is** to use `substr` after last iteration

```
$x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';

 for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
 {
     $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
     $x.=$y.",";

 }
if(!empty($arr)) {
    $x = substr($x, 0, -1);
}
 $sql= $x.')";';
 echo $sql."<br /><br />";
```

or you can also place a if condition in loop like this

```
if($i+1 == count($arr)){
    $x.=$y.",";
} else {
    $x.=$y.",";
}
```

Comment: technically that will fail if $arr is empty because then it will remove the "(" from the first string.

Comment: right Jon thanks for pointing,  update the answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 $x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';

 for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
 {
     $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
     if($i!=count($arr)-1)
         $x.=$y.",";

 }

 $sql= $x.')";';
 echo $sql."<br /><br />";
```

I added the condition to check if it is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';

for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
{
     $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
     if($i == count($arr)-1){
          $x.=$y;
     } else {
          $x.=$y.",";
     }

}
$sql= $x.')";';
echo $sql."<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';
for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
{
   $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
   if ($i < count($arr)-1)  // check if it's the last element or not 
      $x.=$y.",";
   else
      $x=$y;
}
$sql= $x.')";';
```

Or this:

```
$x='"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (';
for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
{
   $y="`$arr[$i]` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
   $x.=$y.",";
}
$x = rtrim($x, ",") // remove the last comma
$sql= $x.')";';
```

or **even better**, just use `implode` to convert the array into a comma-separated string. Like this:

```
$x = $arr;
array_walk($x, function(&$value, $key) { $value = '`' . $value . '` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL'; });
$sql = '"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (' . implode(',', $x) . ')";';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of other ways:

```
$x = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
     $y = "`${arr[$i]}` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
     $x .= ($x ? '' : ',') . $y;
}
$sql = '"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (' . $x . ')";';
echo $sql . "<br /><br />";
```

Or:

```
$cols = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
     $cols[] = "`${arr[$i]}` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
}
$sql = '"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (' . implode(',', $cols) . ')";';
echo $sql . "<br /><br />";
```

Comment: I quite like the second way, it builds a list and then joins it nicely. But that's just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, common, 5 answers and **optimal solution** is to use *subsrt*?
This

```
$sql = '"CREATE TABLE MyGuests (`'.implode("` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,`", $arr).'` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)";';
```

will do exactly the same in one string

[PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ckuh-ajb1)